# F# Pass string to List

Tags: f#, operators, parameter-passing

In F# you can pass a string to an int via the `|>` operator like this:

```
"54" |> int
```

I was wondering if there is a way to do that for list like this:

```
"[4;2;3]" |> list
```

When trying to do this for a list it errors that the value or constructor is not defined.

Perhaps this is not possible at all?

Comment: What do you expect the result to be for "[4;2;3]" |> list ?

Comment: a regular list [4;2;3] that i can extract the elements from and work with

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`int` is a function that can convert a string (and other things) into an int.

There is no built-in function called `list`. To make a list you could use the list literal syntax: `[4;2;3]`

If you need to parse a string like `"[4;2;3]"` into an `int list` then you're on your own. You'd need to write code to do that. For example:

```
let parseIntList (str:string) =
    let trimmed = str.Trim()
    if not (trimmed.StartsWith "[" && trimmed.EndsWith "]") then failwith "Not a list"
    trimmed.[1 .. trimmed.Length - 2].Split ';'
    |> Array.map int
    |> Array.toList
```

This function works for your example but it may fail for other valid inputs.

Comment: Should that not be `int is a constructor that can construct an int from a string` ?

Comment: According to the documentation of `int`, it is indeed not a constructor, but wraps the static `Int32.Parse` (did not manage to find the source code location yet)

Comment: It's a function defined here: https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/4.0.1.20/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/prim-types.fs#L4298

Comment: so "1;2;3".Split ';'  |> Array.map int |> Array.toList will give me the desired list. This helped me alot. Thanks!